# How to call external javascript function from jslib plugin Unity webgl

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm working on a webgl project now and I'm trying to call javascript function in index.html from plugin.jslib

I did google some methods and seems they're not working.
Is there a proper and simple way to do this?

below codes are the ones that i tried.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>%UNITY_WEB_NAME%</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
    <script src="TemplateData/UnityProgress.javascript"></script>
    <script src="%UNITY_WEBGL_LOADER_URL%"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.CheckLoad = function(){ window.alert('It is working!!'); };
    </script>
    <script>
        var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "%UNITY_WEBGL_BUILD_URL%", {onProgress: UnityProgress});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 ...
</body>
</html>
```

plugin.jslib

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library {
    Loaded: function()
    {
        window.CheckLoad();
    },
});
```

Unity C# script

```
public class blablabla : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void Loaded();

    public static void IsLoaded()
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL
        Loaded();
#endif
    }

    void Start()
    {
        IsLoaded();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in console?

Comment: @Papa Actually, there was a build error. so was not able to test it.

Comment: @Papa So I figured it out. and the problem was my mistake of using jslib. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well.. I was stupid.
turned out it was my mistake and the way to do these stuffs are quite easy.

For those who might have same question, check below codes.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>%UNITY_WEB_NAME%</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
    <script src="TemplateData/UnityProgress.javascript"></script>
    <script src="%UNITY_WEBGL_LOADER_URL%"></script>
    <script>
        var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "%UNITY_WEBGL_BUILD_URL%", {onProgress: UnityProgress});

        function CheckLoad(){
           window.alert("WORKING~!");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 ...
</body>
</html>
```

plugin.jslib

```
var plugin = {
    Loaded: function()
    {
        CheckLoad();
    }
};

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, plugin);
```

Comment: I have my JS function within DOMContentLoaded event in a script.js file. And trying to call it from the .jslib file. But I'm getting a ReferenceError: [function name] is not defined.

The .js file is added to the html page with a script tag.

Comment: Just to answer my own question, I added the functions on DOM load, and that didn't work. window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {...}
Putting the functions in the .js file root, made them available. I suppose it's somekind of race condition.